# How to show image from MySql database in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, image, flask

I have the following model. I successfully insert the data to mysql database, but I cannot show the image in the index page. How can I show LargeBinary object from mysql as an image in my template?

```
class ginfo(db.Model):

    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(20))
    comment=db.Column(db.String(1000))
    picdata=db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
```

I got the variables from the page as:

```
        name=request.form['name']
        comment=request.form['comment']
        file=request.files['inputFile']
```

and insert data into mysql with :

```
    signature=ginfo(name=name,comment=comment,picdata=file.read())
    db.session.add(signature)
    db.session.commit()
```

I query the whole rows and columns with :

```
    result=ginfo.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html',result=result)
```

I am trying to show the data as follows:

```
{%for r in result%}
<div class="page-header">
<h1>{{r.name}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="well">
<p>{{r.comment}}</p>
</div>
<img src={base64.decodestring(r.picdata)}/>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: `<img src` references a URL, so probably you need another controller that loads the image and serves it as such?

Comment: You can save the image on the filesystem of your server. And store the path to the image in your database.

Comment: I rather prefer saving my files into the database. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this for example with having a route to serve your image data as a response, e.g. create:

```
@app.route('/img/<int:img_id>')
def serve_img(img_id):
    pass # look up via id, create response with appropriate mimetype
```

And in the template, refer to this route:

```
{% for r in result %}
<img src="{{ url_for('serve_img', img_id=r.id)}}"
{% endfor %}
```

Another approach would be to directly embed the image in your response using a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), basically base64 encode your data and include it in your rendered respone page directly.

I'd personally avoid the second approach, as encoding as base64 will increase size by about 30%, and having the image embedded as a data url will also prevent effective caching by the client.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will give it a try :)

Comment: Hi!, can you please complete the example with real return sentence to use in the end point serve_img(img_id)?. I'd like to implement your suggestion. THANKS IN ADVANCE.